# Third party redirects to browser, not backend

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Hello and thank you in advance.

We are running our Node.js/Express application in App Engine which serves a React front end as static files. At one point the user is able to redirect to a third-party so that the user can sign in and authorize some of their data which is managed by that third-party. We provide the redirect URI to the third-party as a parameter in the querystring, which is https://www.example.com/api/thirdparty/OAuthCallback.

When the user submits the authorization on the third-party side, they should be redirected to that URI, which is an API endpoint in our application where we process the result, and then in our backend we redirect the user to their dashboard. Instead, the user gets redirected to that URI in the browser.

We know (we think) we are doing the routing correctly because we are able to hit that end point from Postman and simulate the process that way.

The question is, why is this redirection going to the browser and not our backend?

Below you will find our server entry point (index.js) along with the route we expect to hit (thirdparty.js)

index.js:

```
    //index.js

import express from "express";
import thirdparty from "./routes/thirdparty";
import httpsRedirect from "./middlewares/https-redirect";

const app = express();

var httpsPort = app.get('https-port');

app.use(httpsRedirect({httpsPort: httpsPort}));
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build')));
app.use("/api/thirdparty", thirdparty);

app.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('new request from: '+req);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080, ()=>console.log('Listening on port 8080'));
```

thirdparty.js (route):

```
    // thirdparty.js
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
var oauth2 = require('./lib/OAuth2.0')();

router.get('/OAuthCallback', function (req, res) {
  console.log("CODE--------------------------- : " + req.query.code);
  var params = {
    code: req.query.code,
    redirect_uri: 'https://www.example.com/api/thirdparty/OAuthCallback'
  }
  oauth2.authCode.getOAuthToken(params, saveToken);
  function saveToken(error, result) {
    // do things with the result
    res.redirect(process.env.HOST+"/dashboard");
  }
});

export default router;
```